# Cutomize of finish button in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I'm making installer in Install4j and I need to customize 'Finish' button on 'Finish screen'.
To customize I mean - to change its title and color. Is there any way how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: 7.0.1 - I believe its the lastest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the text of the button is done by executing

```
context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonText(ControlButtonType.NEXT, "My text");
```

in the "Post-activation script" property of the screen.

For changing the style of the button, go to the Installer->Styles step, copy the "Banner" style and the "Standard footer" style and select the copied footer style in the "Nested style" form component of the copied banner style.

In the copied footer style, select the "Next button" form component and edit the "Initialization script" property to customize the button, for example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
configurationObject.setBackground(Color.GREEN)
```

Finally, go back to Installer->Screens & Actions, select the "Finish" screen and set the "Style" property to the copied banner style.